# to install disc brake

Tags: mountain-bike, disc-brake

Hi friends I have a hercules roadeo a100 and I want to install a disc brake to it. It comes with a disc brake in front and v brake in rear. So can I install a disc brake to it and how much it costs.

Comment: So, you want to replace V-brakes with disk brakes? There are a bunch of questions on this already, try searching (box on top right).

Comment: Probably cheaper to just buy a new bike.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you have disc brake mounting tabs on the seat stays.

[image: Rear Disc Brake Mounts]

If you don't have those, then it's pretty much impossible. Technically still possible, but not without added costs that go well beyond what your bike is worth.

Also, you need to make sure your rear hub has mounting holes for the disc.

[image: Rear Hub Disc Mounts]

If you don't have these, you will need to replace the hub or the wheel.  In your case it would probably be better to just replace the entire wheel.

Your bike is pretty low end.  If you are having braking issues, first make sure everything is adjusted properly.  Then perhaps consider getting a higher quality v-brake with good brake pads. This upgrade will be cheaper and will provide more than adequate braking power.

Answer (score 0):

For the rear wheel you need a specific wheel hub that you can attach a disc to, assuming your frame supports disc brakes in the rear (check answer from @Kibbee). My advice is to just forget this.

In the front however, since your bike already has discs, the change is really easy. You can buy really good price-for-money Shimanos for example, as you can see [here](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/us/en/shimano-acera-m395-disc-brake/rp-prod119954?gs=1&gclid=Cj0KEQjwvuuqBRDG95yR6tmfg9oBEiQAjE3RQI6vH2F_nDyLlAAyiz8XyjIlYYjsfJwhzurwk_G0P7oaAu7s8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds). You will notice a big difference, and doing so implies just removing old lever and caliper and attach new ones. Super easy, and you don't even need to change the disc.

The caliper might need a special adaptor. This depends on your fork and disc size, and I can't advice you without a picture, but Google "bike disc brake adapters" and you will find all the info you need.

I think this shift for hydraulics will be worth it, as you will notice a big difference and they are really cheap.

Happy braking!